# Is it normal to have so little human interaction in R&D?

Tags: work-environment, relationships

Being employed as a fresh CS graduate for a few months now, I started to introspect the atmosphere at our company which seems lacking human interaction. I know that main task of computer engineer is to develop stuff and solve problems using computer, but in our R&D department, we sit mostly all day being away from the computer only for lunch and when going to the bathroom. Same goes for talking, which is a few sentences per day (since everyone is working on their problem). I can't imagine being like this for next 5 or 10 years.

The company I work for is dealing with embedded systems and it has about 40 employees. The R&D departemnt consists of 15 developers being in two offices, our being smaller with 5 developers.

Honestly, I imagined my job as a software developer would be more engaging. Is this atmosphere normal for R&Ds around the world or am I just being part of a weird team? Did I have wrong expectations of my career? I have no experience with any other company which makes it hard to compare.

Comment: Please do explain the downvotes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Why do many downvotes? The OP is new to the workplace and "the workplace", and he wants to know what's it's like out there. Valid question to me.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Let's say it's normal. Your problem still exists, nothing has been solved, and people who find this question will just be disappointed. If you [edit] your question to be in line with our [help/dont-ask], for instance, *"How can I increase the amount of human interaction while doing R&D?"* you will get better answers that provide more value in the future. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "How can I increase the amount of human interaction while doing R&D?" is a lot more opinion based than "Is it normal to have so little human interaction in R&D?", that just ask about a fact: if other R&D departments are this way. I think the question should be opened - in fact, it shouldn't have been closed.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience this is definitely a growing trend in the IT industry generally, not just R&D. Occasionally you will bump into people who are friendly and personable, but the vast majority seem stressed and oppressed by job insecurity, micro-management, skills gaps or other work issues, or they are just naturally introverted.

I suspect this is the root cause of your anonymouse down-votes - I'm bracing myself to cop a few with this answer :-)

My main strategy is to try to find something in common with co-workers that has nothing to do with the current work - it could be sport, family, hobbies, travel - whatever.  Once you have found something it can be the thread for a series of brief conversations with them, that break up your day.

Most workplaces will tolerate a limited amount of this but be careful to carry on any lengthy conversations "off the clock" e.g. on a break or out of office hours.

I stay well away from any contentious topics they might raise, no matter how strongly I might feel about them personally.

Long-term, these human connections will become your network of people who mutually help each other to progress their careers.

Answer (score 1):

Different companies operate differently. You need to ask more questions about the copmany culture when you interview to find a better fit for you.

In many businesses the ability to interact with users and management is valued and i nmany places devs are expected to get together and brainstorm. Some places like total quiet and others like a lot of give and take.

You might be happier in a place with an open office plan as there is typically more interaction and noise. You might also find that the type of atmosphere you prefer tends to happen more at places that do not specialize in software but where it is a cost center not a profit center.  So ask about the culture when you loook for future jobs and find a place where intereaction with others is common and you will be happier.

Answer (score 1):

No this does sound very unusual.

RnD is by its nature a corroborative endeavour when I worked  at a world leading  RnD organisation (ranked no 1 in the world) based on an elite university campus, there was a lot of interaction between staff.

I still recall  some of the fun brain storming sessions we had in our office discussing solutions to problems “how do you measure the efficiency of a toilet cistern in order to save water “ being one example.

Also do you not discuss interesting articles in the industry magazines/publications you do all have general science  magazines like New Scientist Scientific American and Nature plus industry mags on your office distribution list.

I would suggest  to management that there are regular lunchtime seminars (with lunch provided) given by staff members and outside guests on the area of their work.